# When I use Cmake to compile the file, it shows /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ltest. However when I use g++ to compile the file, it is ok

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake

This is the CMakeList.txt in src directory:

> ADD_EXECUTABLE(Expression ExpressionValue.cpp)
>   INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(/root/fengwu/codes/headfiles/expression/include)
>   LINK_DIRECTORIES(/root/fengwu/codes/headfiles/expression/lib)
>   TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(Expression test)

When I enter `cmake ..` in build directory, it is ok. After that I enter `make`, it shows `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ltest`. However when I use g++, it is ok.

> g++ ExpressionValue.cpp
>   -I/root/fengwu/codes/headfiles/expression/include -L/root/fengwu/codes/headfiles/expression/lib -ltest -o expr.out

Comment: Have you built your library test? At least the CMakeLists.txt does not mention it.

Comment: when I enter make VERBOSE=1, it is also the same,/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ltest. @user1034749

Comment: Of course I have built my library, I can compile the file correctly when I use g++, and it can run correctly. The last line in the CMakeLists.txt should link the library. @usr1234567

Comment: With verbose we are interested in the linker invoking. Please provide that. Why do you not build the test library with CMake? It it located in the build directory? We are lacking some information to help you.

Comment: The library is built before using g++ xxx.cpp -fPIC -shared -o libtest.so . I just want to link this library using cmake. @usr1234567

Comment: Can you give the complete path to `test` and the build directory of `Expression`?

Comment: I am a fresh man to Linux and cmake.So maybe I cannot answer your question correctly.libtest.so is in (/root/fengwu/codes/headfiles/expression/lib),I use INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES in CMakeList.txt.The project is in folder expression, there are three folders and a CMakeList.txt in it, which are src,build,and include. In src, there are two file ExpressionValue.cpp, CMakeList.txt. In folder include, there is a headfile. The content of CMakeList.txt in folder expression are :PROJECT (Expression) CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8)SET(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(src bin).@usr1234567

Comment: Part of the verbose, it is too long to print.Linking CXX executable Expression
cd /root/fengwu/codes/headfiles/expression/build/src && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/Expression.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++       CMakeFiles/Expression.dir/ExpressionValue.cpp.o  -o Expression -rdynamic -ltest 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ltest
@usr1234567

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation for [link_directories](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/link_directories.html):

> The command will apply only to targets created after it is called.

For make `link_directories()` call work you need to move it **before** `add_executable()`.

Comment: @mrbrant: Please accept the answer, then everybody can see that your problem is solved.