# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lruby

Tags: c, ruby, cmake

I hope build ruby c extension with cmake, but I get `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibruby` in console, here is my code:

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -std=c11")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
file(GLOB cs *.c)

include_directories($ENV{HOME}/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/include/ruby-2.2.0/x86_64-linux
        $ENV{HOME}/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/include/ruby-2.2.0)

foreach (c ${cs})
    get_filename_component(exe ${c} NAME_WE)
    add_executable(${exe} ${cs})
endforeach ()

add_library(mytest SHARED MyTest.c)
link_directories($ENV{HOME}/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib)
find_library(ruby NAMES ruby)
target_link_libraries(mytest ruby)
```

and here is ruby lib:

```
roroco@roroco-Zhaoyang-K49 ~/Dropbox/rbs/ro_plans $ lsa ~/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib
total 61424
drwxr-xr-x 4 roroco roroco     4096 Nov 21 23:49 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 roroco roroco     4096 Oct 13 22:10 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 roroco roroco       16 Nov 21 23:49 libruby.so -> libruby.so.2.2.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 roroco roroco       16 Nov 21 23:49 libruby.so.2.2 -> libruby.so.2.2.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 roroco roroco 13573794 Nov 21 23:49 libruby.so.2.2.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 roroco roroco 49306632 Nov 21 23:47 libruby-static.a
drwxr-xr-x 2 roroco roroco     4096 Nov 21 23:49 pkgconfig
drwxr-xr-x 6 roroco roroco     4096 Oct 13 22:10 ruby
```

Comment: It needs to be `ruby` not `libruby`. The `-l` will add the `lib` part.

Comment: @kaylum It doesn't work, even i change libruby to ruby, it still raise error.

Comment: You have the library in a non-standard location. You need to add that directory into your cmake. I'm not a cmake expert but believe the command for that is `link_directories`.

Comment: @kaylum I add link_directories and update my question, I still get same error

Comment: `find_library` call is useless here. `link_directories` call should come **before** `add_librarary` for take effect (see that [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33562025/3440745)).

Comment: 1) Your find_library syntax is poor because you're using the library name as the output variable. That itself is probably not more than poor coding style, but .....
2) You're using that name directly in target_link_libraries. You would need target_link_libraries(mytest ${ruby}). You should try adding something like message("ruby library: ${ruby}") to see how you're variable is getting set.