# How to set a search library path in CMake?

Tags: xcode, cmake

I'm trying to add `/usr/local/lib` to the Xcode library search paths when I generate the Xcode files through CMake but I can't get CMake to add it.

Would any of you know how?

`link_directories(/usr/local/lib)` doesn't work.

Comment: `... but I can't get CMake to add it.` - Why do you think that CMake doesn't add it? Show the code which uses that.

Comment: It doesn't add it to Xcode. I have to manually add it to Xcode after it generates the Xcode build files. Cause XCode complains about it. So I have to add that line to the "Library Search Paths" manually in XCode.

Comment: I can add a header search path through cmake but not a library search path:
http://imgur.com/NqwPa05

Comment: Just a guess: You issue `link_directories` command **after** `add_executable`. In that case your executable doesn't get additional directories for search libraries. See [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33992880/cmakes-link-directories-issue-with-static-library-on-mac-os-x) for more details.