# Adding static dependency in CMake

Tags: cmake

I've got an example project:

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
└── src
    └── test1.f90
```

where test1.f90 uses a specific version of Lapack (therefore I can't use FindLAPACK).

I am trying to compile this using CMake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.5)
project(TEST)

file(GLOB_RECURSE sources  src/*.f90)

add_executable(cmake.x ${sources})

enable_language(Fortran)
set(CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER_ID "IBM")


if(CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "IBM")
    set(CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_LINK_Fortran_FLAGS)
    MESSAGE(STATUS "IBM")
    SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-Wl,-allow-multiple-definition ")
    set(CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER mpixlf2008_r)
    set(debug "-C")
endif()


set(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS_DEBUG} ${bounds}")
set(CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS "${CMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS} ${dialect}")

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/Modules/")
MESSAGE( STATUS "cmake_module_path:    " ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH})
```

If I run `make VERBOSE=1` this results in:

```
...
[100%] Building Fortran object CMakeFiles/cmake.x.dir/src/test1.o
mpixlf2008_r    -c /work/jias12/jias1217/lapack_test/src/test1.f90 -o CMakeFiles/cmake.x.dir/src/test1.o
** main   === End of Compilation 1 ===
1501-510  Compilation successful for file test1.f90.
Linking Fortran executable cmake.x
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmake.x.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
mpixlf2008_r   -Wl,-allow-multiple-definition    CMakeFiles/cmake.x.dir/src/test1.o  -o cmake.x  
CMakeFiles/cmake.x.dir/src/test1.o:(.text+0x5c): undefined reference to `sgesv'
make[2]: *** [cmake.x] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/work/jias12/jias1217/lapack_test'
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmake.x.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/work/jias12/jias1217/lapack_test'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

This obviously doesn't work, because I didn't include LAPACK, which I then can do manually:

```
mpixlf2008_r   -Wl,-allow-multiple-definition    CMakeFiles/cmake.x.dir/src/test1.o  -o cmake.x -L$LAPACK_LIB -L/bgsys/local/lib -llapack -lesslbg
```

Which works fine. How can I achieve this using CMake? I want to add `-L$LAPACK_LIB -L/bgsys/local/lib -llapack -lesslbg` to the linker after the *.o files. All I've managed is to add them as flags before the *.o files, which fails. I've look at a number of examples on the web, but I cannot find something which works in my case. This is the [test1.f90](https://pastebin.com/M2ZZGEmw).

This is in the folders:

```
 > ls $LAPACK_LIB
libblas_extra.a  libcblas.a  liblapack.a  liblapacke.a  libtmglib.a
ls /bgsys/local/lib/
BGeic.pm  BG.pm  libesslbg.a  libesslsmpbg.a
```

Comment: What is wrong with [target_link_libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/target_link_libraries.html) which links with the libraries (meaning of flag `-l`) and [link_directories](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/link_directories.html) which specifies libraries search path (meaning of flag `-L`)?

Comment: If I add those I get:
`mpixlf2008_r   -Wl,-allow-multiple-definition    CMakeFiles/cmake.x.dir/src/test1.o  -o cmake.x  -llapack -lesslbg 
ld: cannot find -llapack
ld: cannot find -lesslbg`
The -L doesn't seem to appear. Could you be more verbose about this? This is the full output: https://pastebin.com/VmypK5nM

Comment: `link_directories()` call should come **before** `add_executable()`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33992880/cmakes-link-directories-issue-with-static-library-on-mac-os-x/33994624#33994624. Also, it is better to issue `add_executable()` **after** the `project()` call and `enable_language()`.

Comment: Ok thanks this worked. I will post the working version as an answer for other people who stumple upon this post.

Answer (score 0):

As Tsyvarev correctly mentioned:

> What is wrong with [target_link_libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_link_libraries.html) which links with the
>   libraries (meaning of flag -l) and [link_directories](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/link_directories.html) which specifies
>   libraries search path (meaning of flag -L)?

Those hase to be called in the right order, which leads to:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.5)
project(TEST)

file(GLOB_RECURSE sources  src/*.f90)

link_directories($ENV{LAPACK_LIB} /bgsys/local/lib)
enable_language(Fortran)

add_executable(cmake.x ${sources})
target_link_libraries(cmake.x lapack esslbg)
```